# Listing values regardless of prompt selection

Tags: cognos

I currently have a cognos report with 3 pages:

- Monthly Summary
- Monthly Detailed
- Full Year Trend

The month is determined by a value prompt. My question is: How can I make it so the 3rd report page ignores the Month paramvalue and shows all 12 months regardless of the value prompt? So if June, for example, was picked the first two reports would show only June but the full year trend would show January to December.

Currently the prompt works fine for the two other reports but I can't figure out how to make the third page show the same data everytime.

Thanks,

lostintern

Answer (score 0):

It will get tricky towards year-end/beginning, but anyhow ... Extract the value of Year from your prompt and use it as a filter for your third page query.

Comment: If (?ReportSelect? = 'FullYear') then ([MONTH YYYYMM] between to_char(current_date, 'YYYY')+'00' and to_char(current_date, 'YYYY')+'13')  else ([MONTH YYYYMM] between to_char(current_date, 'YYYY')+'00' and ?Month?) is what I went with, thanks for your help though. I forgot to update this question.